# SQL Email based on query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have set up SQL server to email and have successfully. I am trying to send an email with the following query:

```
select count(*) from report queue
```

I would like an email sent when `count` is > 10.

I have never done a SQL stored procedure before.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM report_queue
HAVING ct > 10
```

Comment: Nice succinct solution.

Comment: Column is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Anon I don't use SQL Server, but other SQL implementations allow referring to any `SELECT` aliases in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
select email from report queue group by email having count(*)>10
```

Comment: This will do per-email counts, not a total count like in his question.

Comment: It is not really clear what is the question... maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative;

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [report queue]) > 10)

SELECT * FROM [report queue]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[email_report] (@recipients nvarchar(max), @subject nvarchar(max) = '', @body nvarchar(max) = '')
AS
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [report_queue]) > 10
  EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]
    @recipients = @recipients,
    @subject = @subject,
    @body = @body;   
END
```

More details available here: [sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)